# solr clobtransfomer

Tags: oracle, solr, clob, dataimporthandler

I am stuck with `ClobTransformer` in solr from the past 3 days. I want to convert an oracle clob field to text field in solr. I am using multiple cores and I started my config and schema files from scratch.

This is my config file:

```
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />

<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

These are the columns in my schema file for a core:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
<field name="mandp" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

This is my data-config.xml for the core:

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
              driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@***" 
              user="***"
              password="****"/>
    <document>
        <entity name="wiki" transformer="ClobTransformer"
                 query="Select t.id as id, t.mandp From table1 t">
            <field column="mandp" name="mandp" clob="true" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

When I start solr, I can see that dataimporthandler*.jar files have loaded successfully in the console. When I run my dataimport from `http://localhost:8983/solr/wiki/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=false`, I don't see any errors in the console neither do I see anything related to transformer or clob. So, If I type anything in my transformer parameter (transformer="bla bla bla"), it doesn't throw any errors in the console, that could mean my transformer argument is completely ignored or the full logging is turned off.

When I query solr, I see **oracle.sql.CLOB@375c929a** in the mandp field. Nothing happens of course if I use HTMLStripTransformer class too. I want to use both on this field.

Any ideas are appreciated!!!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the `ClobTransformer` is not fired. I would personally change the `mandp` column name inside the query like this:

```
Select t.id as id, t.mandp as mandp From table1 t
```

Comment: I changed my query to "Select id, mandp From table1". It didn't make a difference.

Comment: Found what was happening, it was column case mismatch. Oracle converts id to ID and mandp to MANDP. So, the field match was never found and hence clob="true" wasn't applied (I knew that in solr cases had to match, but I forgot oracle will convert all the columns to upper case by default)

Comment: yeah, you're right, I forgot it as well. I wasn't so far...it had to be something related to the column name.

Answer (score -1):

please add transformer="ClobTransformer, RegexTransformer" to the entity in your data-config.xml file